# Нужна критика проекта PyQt5 + QThread + OpenCV

Tags: pyqt5, инспекция-кода, opencv

Изучаю QThread. Есть рабочий проект c OpenCV. Я его запустил, но у меня при рабочей вэбке и перетаскивании окна по экрану начинает передвигаться это окно не плавно. Хочу услышать мнения специалистов. Какие замечания, как бы Вы его оформили? Правильно ли подобные проекты также делить на три файла? Какие изменения нужны для правильного написания? Хочу увидеть ваши версии.

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from views import UI_Window
from models import Camera

if __name__ == '__main__':

    camera = Camera(0)

    app = QApplication([])
    start_window = UI_Window(camera)
    start_window.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
```

***views.py***

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from models import Camera

class UI_Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, camera = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera
        print('UI')
        # Create a timer.
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)

        # Create a layout.
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Add a button
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        btnCamera = QPushButton("Open camera")
        btnCamera.clicked.connect(self.start)
        button_layout.addWidget(btnCamera)
        layout.addLayout(button_layout)

        # Add a label
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setFixedSize(640, 640)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Set the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("First GUI with QT")
        #self.setFixedSize(800, 800)

    def start(self):
        if not self.camera.open():
            print('failure')
            msgBox = QMessageBox()
            msgBox.setText("Failed to open camera.")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return

        self.timer.start(1000. / 24)

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        frame = self.camera.read()
        #frame = self.camera.read_gray()
        if frame is not None:
            image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
            self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)


class MovieThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = camera

    def run(self):
        self.camera.acquire_movie(200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = UI_Window()
    window.show()
```

***models.py***

```
mport cv2

class Camera:

    def __init__(self, camera):
        self.camera = camera
        self.vp = None

    def open(self, width=640, height=480, fps=30):
        self.vc = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera)

        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        # vc.set(5, fps)  #set FPS
        self.vc.set(3, width)   # set width
        self.vc.set(4, height)  # set height

        return self.vc.isOpened()

    def read(self, negative=False):
        rval, frame = self.vc.read()
        if frame is not None:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            if negative:
                frame = cv2.bitwise_not(frame)
            return frame

    def read_gray(self, negative=False):
        rval, frame = self.vc.read()
        if frame is not None:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            if negative:
                frame = cv2.bitwise_not(frame)
            return frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот код и прост, и окно перемещается плавно при включенной камере.

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import cv2

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.VBL = QVBoxLayout()

        self.FeedLabel = QLabel()
        self.VBL.addWidget(self.FeedLabel)

        self.CancelBTN = QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.CancelBTN.clicked.connect(self.CancelFeed)
        self.VBL.addWidget(self.CancelBTN)

        self.Worker1 = Worker1()

        self.Worker1.start()
        self.Worker1.ImageUpdate.connect(self.ImageUpdateSlot)
        self.setLayout(self.VBL)

    def ImageUpdateSlot(self, Image):
        self.FeedLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))

    def CancelFeed(self):
        self.Worker1.stop()

class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    def run(self):
        self.ThreadActive = True
        Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self.ThreadActive:
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:
                Image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                FlippedImage = cv2.flip(Image, 1)
                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(FlippedImage.data, FlippedImage.shape[1], FlippedImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(Pic)
    def stop(self):
        self.ThreadActive = False
        self.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Root = MainWindow()
    Root.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```